# Fixing signage flush to concrete block

Tags: concrete

I have a number of large aluminium signs (4ft x 3ft) that I need to fix flush to pre-cast concrete slabs.  Ideally I would like the fixings to be invisible rather than screw heads which will be visible and have been trying to source some kind of solution to no avail - Can anyone advise please?
Many thanks

Comment: Counter sunk screws are the normal way to attach a plate with the heads flush. This requires a bit that makes a tapered hole the screw head sits in [like this](https://m.lowes.com/pd/IRWIN-1-2-in-Black-Oxide-Twist-Drill-Bit/50247075?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-ToolsAndHardware-_-PowerToolAccessories-_-50247075:IRWIN&CAWELAID=&kpid=50247075&CAGPSPN=pla&store_code=2940&k_clickID=ea985018-4ea8-457c-a30f-c94373a534b8) with this [kind of screw](http://m.ebay.com/itm/190823944258?_mwBanner=1) that one was for wood but there are ones for cement available at most home stores

Answer (score 2):

I would try a construction glue in a caulking-gun

[image]
<sup>Random example from Internet, any product with same characteristics will do</sup>

> - Waterproof: Can be used in interior or **exterior** applications
> - Versatile: For use on wood, **metal**, plastic, foam, mirror, **concrete** and brick

---

I've used a similar sort of adhesive to attach small plastic signs to rough granite, with mixed success. Some lessons -

- You need the surfaces to be clean, dry and free from dust or loose debris.
- If the back of the sign is very smooth, it *might* be worth experimenting with roughening it with sandpaper. This may depend on the specifiic adhesive.
- When fixing signs on a vertical surface, I found it best to support the sign until the adhesive sets. I fabricated a temporary support using scrap wood and other materials.

Comment: +1 Just be sure the concrete is clean, dry, and any dust has been removed.

Comment: @bib: good point thanks, I'll elaborate the answer a bit.